# Change link color when using LinkMovementMethod and Html.fromHtml

Tags: android

I am using using Html.fromHtml to set the corresponding text for a TextView object.  Said HTML has url links that I want users to be able to click on and open the browser to that link.  I am using LinkMovementMethod to accomplish that fine and dandy.  The problem is the link markup is coloring it in the traditional dark blue against a black background, this is bad.  I'd like to keep the blackbackground color and change the link color to a lighter blue.  How can I do this?

Here is a brief code snippet...

```
TextView servicesTextView = (TextView)activity.get().findViewById(R.id.ServicesText);
servicesTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(servicesText));
servicesTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 37):

Boy, each time I finally write a up a question on StackOverflow, I end up finding the answer myself.

`TextView` has [`setLinkTextColor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLinkTextColor%28int%29) method.

Comment: To set in xml, use: `android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"` . Thanks!

Comment: to actually set in xml, use: `android:textColorLink="@color/dark_blue"`